# Glassfish and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy with javassist.jar in lib. Why have I this error?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, glassfish

I want to use Glassfish and hibernate. I use the Glassfish update tool to add the hibernate libraries.

So I have all needed libraries.

But when I ran my JUnit test I have this exception :

java.lang.RuntimeException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: How do you run your JUnit test exactly? What do you have on your classpath?

Comment: I use Netbeans to run my tests. So, all libraries are in the classpath. But it seems that a conflict exists between the antlr version used by glassfish and hibernate. I switched to EclipseLink and it's works fine. But I would like to use hibernate.